# Should I give source code if client owns the IP

Tags: intellectual-property, software

I signed a contract with one of my clients containing the following line:

> All such intellectual property of the developed solution shall belong to {the client} and {The Service provider} shall assign all its rights in Developed IP to {the client}

There is no mention at all to the source code. Should I give them the source code anyways?

Comment: The source code is IP. And if the source code was developed for the client, then it belongs to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ShazamoMorebucks mentioned, your source code is considered part of the intellectual property that you created for your client.

From [Cuttlesoft.com](https://www.cuttlesoft.com/ip-and-source-code-ownership/):

> There are also circumstances in which code that you write is automatically owned by someone else. This is called “work made for hire,” and includes any code written as an employee of a larger company, or under a contract with a client.

Also from [the same Cuttlesoft page](https://www.cuttlesoft.com/ip-and-source-code-ownership/) (written with the client as the intended audience):

> When working with a developer, you are hiring them to provide a service, rather than a product. The service they provide should not entitle them to ownership of the resulting software. When hiring a contractor to construct a building, you wouldn’t expect them to ask for partial ownership, so why should a coder expect to own a piece of the source code?